Does it make sense that potential yields under high inputs could be lower than those under low inputs in GAEZ?
I'm using GAEZ data for the first time and noticed that for some crops, potential yields under low inputs are higher than under high inputs.
I found some explaination in the documentation, it says even under high-input systems, certain agro-climatic constraints, like dry soil conditions, can have a more severe impact and limit yields.
Can anyone confirm this? I've emailed the GAEZ team but haven't heard back yet.
